# Select rows which minimum value between 2 columns match condition

Tags: sql-server

I am running sql server 2012. 
My table looks like this:

```
EventID | EventDate1 | EventDate2
      1 | 01/06/2016 | 02/06/2016
      2 | 04/06/2016 | 02/06/2016
      3 | NULL       | 03/06/2016
      4 | 01/06/2016 | NULL
```

Given a specific day, I need to select all events with earliest date happened on that day.

So if user choose 01/06, I would want to show them `EventID 1` and `EventID 4`. As for 02/06, I want to show the `EventID 2`. Similarly, on day 3 I need to show `EventID 3`. In this case, day 4 would have no result because the EventID 2 happened at day 2 already.

Here's how I get the a list of earliest event from the above table: - got this somewhere in stackoverflow

```
Select EventID, EventDate1, EventDate2,
Case When EventDate2 < EventDate1 Then EventDate2
     when EventDate1 is null then EventDate2
     else EventDate1
     End As TheMin
From   Event
```

From this table, I will have to select the rows where TheMin = input date. And here I'm stuck. I can't use TheMin in the where clause.

So.. how can I achieve what I need ?

**EDIT**

As DineshDB said, I edited my question so that it's clearer.

I want to select all EventID which happened first at 02/06.

Result should be

```
 EventID | EventDate1 | EventDate2
       2 | 04/06/2016 | 02/06/2016
```

Although Event 1 happened *earlier*, it fist occur is at 01/06. So it won't be in the result for 02/06, therefore the result for 02/06 should only be Event 2, which first happens at 02/06.

Both the EventDate columns are equal, there's no priority whatsoever.

Comment: Edit the question with your Expected Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @TheMin DATETIME = '11-Jul-2016'

Select *
From
(
    Select EventID, EventDate1, EventDate2,
    Case When EventDate2 < EventDate1 Then EventDate2
         when EventDate1 is null then EventDate2
         else EventDate1
         End As TheMin
    From   Event
) t
Where TheMin = @TheMin
```

Comment: Well for some reason sql doesn't understand "TheMin" in the sub query, that's why i said in my question, I can't use TheMin in the where clause..

Comment: Okay, sorry for my earlier comment, and thanks for the reply. It was my mistake about TheMin that sql doesn't understand. Your answer is indeed the right one for me. Thank you very much